# ARM: Can a FIQ handler pre-empt an executing IRQ handler?

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, drivers, armv7

For the ARMv7 architecture, can a FIQ exception pre-empt a currently executing IRQ handler (in IRQ context of course)

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Yes (that is arguably its primary purpose), unless the IRQ handler has for some crazy reason manually masked FIQs.

IRQs are automatically masked by the core when taking an FIQ exception, but FIQs are not automatically masked by the core when taking an IRQ.

Some, but not all, ARMv6+ processors also support disabling the ability to manually mask FIQs.